# Android EditText with icon and vertical line

Tags: android, mobile, android-edittext

I need an EditText exactly like this:
[EditText with icon and vertical line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlTr5.png)

Is it possible doing this at Android XML file?

Comment: do you want the icon to disappear when you start entering your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this code helps you

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_selector">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/your_icon"
        android:text=""
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background=""
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <!-- icon -->
    <ImageView
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:src="@drawable/perm_group_personal_info"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Use FrameLayout / RelativeLayout.

either way you can position imageButton with the image as src and costume drawable that will have only 1 side line.